# How can I sign a Windows desktop bridge app package on a new computer?

Tags: uwp

I was able to build a package for upload to Microsoft partner center on my old computer.

However, when I build the same project on my new computer in Visual Studio, it encountered an error:

> no certificate found with the specified fingerprint.

It seemed to be a temporary cert (*.pfx) file in the solution explorer under the package project.
But that file doesn't even exist in the hard drive on my old computer.

So how could I build the package after changing the development computer?

Comment: Have you associated your app with the store on the new computer?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, I have.

Comment: Are you using the windows application package project? If it is, could you please check the `Packaging` tab of the Manifest file to see if you are using the correct certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is simple:

1. Create a new bundle project.
2. Associate the bundle project app with the store.
3. Build the package.